# Can Unity check collisions in the reference script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

As you can see in the figure, we are coding the logic of re-creating when the character falls off.
Currently, when you enter the isLeft and isRight scripts, the position becomes true and the opposite side is false.
If the collisions that fall on the floor become true, we respawn the characters where they are true.
The script that manages this isFall.

```
public class isFall : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hood;
    public bool isRight , isLeft;

    public IsRight Position_Right; 
    public IsLeft Position_Left;
    bool isDelay;
    public Health hp;

    private void Awake() {
        isRight = isLeft = false;
        isDelay = false;
    }

    private void Update() {
        if(isDelay){
            StartCoroutine(WaitForSpawn());
            isDelay = false;
        }

        if (Position_Right.isRight)
        {
            isRight = true;
            isLeft = false;
            Position_Left.isLeft = false;
        }

        if (Position_Left.isLeft)
        {
            isLeft = true;
            isRight = false;
            Position_Right.isRight = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
            isDelay = true;
            hp.TakeDamage(1);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForSpawn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        if (isLeft) hood.transform.position = Position_Left.transform.position;
        else hood.transform.position = Position_Right.transform.position; 
    }

}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public class IsLeft : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isLeft = false;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
        if (collider.CompareTag("Player")){
            Debug.Log(" OnTriggerEnter2D = Enter");
            isLeft = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can isFall detect isLeft and isRight OnTriggerEnter2D?
The script works fine,
But I think it would be better to manage it later if I reference it with one script, so I want to know how.

[image: reference image]

Answer (score 0):

No you can't achieve this with `isFall` alone, because the documentation of [OnTriggerEnter2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) says: *Sent when another object enters a trigger collider attached to this object.* You must attach a script on the left or right collider to trigger the callback.

So... if you create a script for the character, it is able to detect all the colliders.

```
public class Character: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider) {
        if (collider.CompareTag("Left"))
            isLeft = true;
        else if (collider.CompareTag("Right"))
            isLeft = false;
        else if (collider.CompareTag("Fall"))
            StartCoroutine(WaitForSpawn());
    }
}
```

BTW a single field `isLeft` is enough, because the respawn position is either left or right.